# Chrome cookies and HTML selectBox.onchange

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way for me to set a chrome cookie everytime it is changed? I've tried

```
    <select id="routeBox" name="routeBox" 
        onchange="getRoute(route, routeBox.selectedIndex); 
            chrome.cookies.set({'url':'http://127.0.0.1/', 'name':'routeCookie', 'value': this.options.selectedIndex});">
    </select>
```

Ignore getRoute, it just calls an xml parser again to re-populate the selectBox. 
The cookie part doesn't seem to work. I've also tried creating a function that is called onchange but it doesn't work either.

```
    <select id="routeBox" name="routeBox" 
        onchange="getRoute(route, routeBox.selectedIndex); 
            setCookies('http://127.0.0.1/','routeCookie', this.options.selectedIndex);">
    </select>

        function setCookies(domain, name, value) {
            chrome.cookies.set({'url': domain, 'name': name, 'value': value});          
            alert("cookie set");
        }
```

Also: Here is a snippet of my manifest file

```
"permissions": [
"cookies", "tabs",
"*://*/*"
],
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["http://127.0.0.1/*", "*://*/*"],
  "js": ["functions.js"]
}
```

As always any help or comments would be great!

Comment: Why don't you just use localStorage? It's much easier to use, just like declaring global variables. According to [Google's documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/cookies.html#method-set), I'm not sure you can sue a comma to set multiple cookies. I think you should try using a semi-colon.

Comment: I'm actually not setting mutiple cookies, but setting attributes to the cookie. What is local storage?

Comment: [Dive Into HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.org/storage.html) and [MDN's Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/storage#localStorage) should explain it well enough. Basically, it's a new way to store variables, even after the page has been shut in HTML5 capable browsers. Which includes Chrome.

Comment: Looking into it, thanks! Do you by any chance know a good example of its usage off of your head?

Comment: Yeah, sure.

<script>localStorage.name = "Amaan"</script> This would store the date in your browser's folder for as long as you don't delete your data for. You can then use it for something like document.write('Your name is '+localStorage.name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amaan Cheval has provided me with this solution:

Use HTML 5 LocalStorage!

This was a simple workaround that while may not be backwards compatible friendly, seems to be able to replace cookies quite effectively.